# Hazelcast much slower than Ignite on single-node map

Tags: benchmarking, hazelcast, ignite

I was running a simple benchmark on Hazelcast (using `JMH`), comparing it with `Apache Ignite`.
This is for a single node deployment.

The cache configuration is left at default,

```
final Config config = new Config();
return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

And I use `put` and `get` with the map,

```
private IMap<Long, Customer> normalCache = hazelcast.getMap( CacheName.NORMAL.getCacheName());
public void saveToCache(Customer customer) {
    normalCache.put(customer.getId(), customer);
}
```

From the results, it seems that Ignite is 3-4X faster than Hazelcast.
I had figured the difference would be much lesser.
Both for Ignite as well as Hazelcast, I haven't used any other optimizations (near caches etc), just went with the default configuration (result is in ops/sec, throughput).

[image]

Is this the expected performance difference or are the results wrong ?

Answer (score 7):

Please run in a client server setup, or with multiple nodes.

AFAIK in case of Ignite, if a local call is done, it is done on the calling thread instead of being offloaded to a partition threads.

Nice for benchmarks, not very useful for production environments because most calls will not be local (in case of a client server setup, no call is local).

Answer (score 3):

You're using a distributed system for a single node deployment??? Really, don't do that, **it's like using a Porsche to drive over a muddy field**. If you want single node try something else like EhCache, I'm guessing you don't need High Availability, Backups etc.

If you do want to choose between Ignite or Hazelcast run a real distributed test.  Start 3 nodes using Client/Server and then see which one is the fastest.

Comment: The idea was basically to see what happens when the data is local to the node, and then also try out distributed data using a cluster afterwords. From the earlier answer, it seems as if there are thread handoff overheads, will try a distributed benchmark.

Comment: Is your production use case Client-Server?  An application will use the client libraries and then connect into a separate running cluster? This is by far the most common pattern of access. If it is, then no call is truly local as @pveentjer says.

Comment: Not really decided on whether it should be client-server or if the Hazelcast node resides within the app node JVM. Would like to evaluate both, and see the trade offs.

Comment: Client-Server or not, you should be testing distributed technologies in distributed ways. For data localisation, suggest that you look into NearCache.